# Unable to obtain configuration from IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker-compose, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

Welcome,
It is my first try of using Docker containers to host to services. I have two services: `Integrity-Identity` and `Integrity-API`.

`Integrity-Identity` is using the latest version of IdentityServer4. Here is `Integrity-Identity` `Startup.cs` configuration:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext<IntegrityIdentityContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["connectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IntegrityIdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
                options.IssuerUri = null;
            })
            .AddSigningCredential(Certificate.Certificate.Get())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddCorsPolicyService<InMemoryCorsPolicyService>();

        RegisterEventBus(services);
        services.AddTransient<Seeder>();

        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.Populate(services);

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        ConfigureEventBus(app);
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Here is `Integrity-API` `Startup` class:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext<IntegrityApiContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["secrets:connectionString"]));

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityUrl"];
                options.ApiName = "integrity_api";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

        services.AddCors(options => { 
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });

        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.Populate(services);

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
    }
```

`docker-compose.override.yml` (I am attaching it but I do not know is this importent for this problem)

```
integrity.identity:
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://0.0.0.0:443
    - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
    - EventBusConnection=rabbitmq
  ports:
    - "5105:443"
  volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

integrity.api:
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443
    - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
    - EventBusConnection=rabbitmq
    - IdentityUrl=https://integrity.identity
    - ApiUrl=https://integrity.api
  ports:
    - "5115:443"
  volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

When I am trying to get resource from controller with `[Authorize]` property and with generated token, `Identity-API` returns this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://integrity.identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() in C:\local\identity\server4\AccessTokenValidation\src\IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.cs:line 61
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

## Edit 1

I forgot to add the `/.well-known/openid-configuration` works in browser and certificate/https is correct and working without any warnings.

Comment: Did you have a chance to cehck if this helps? [Unable to obtain configuration from: '/.well-known/openid-configuration' when hosted on IIS](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/628)

Comment: It is giving me another problem but previous error is still occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution for this issue. The problem was caused for self signed local certificate. For local development I only need to change from HTTPS to HTTP. And that was it.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on what you mean by change https to http? You had already set options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

Comment: I am also facing the same problem while running the identity in docker compose and facing the error "System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:44338/.well-known/openid-configuration" could you please explain it with more detail from where i can change HTTPS to HTTP

Comment: I changed it using project setting by right clicking it in VS.